# Presenting aligned pictures in Elsevier format

Tags: graphics, subfloats, includegraphics

I am trying to present two sub-pictures in Latex format in the following manner.
[image]

To do so, I am using the following codes:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}[t]\vspace*{4pt}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \hspace*{5mm}
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{center}        
    \caption{(a) first picture; (b) second picture.}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

Is there any way I can amend the existing codes to get the figures in the manner I previously presented?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what you mean by "Elsevier format". E.g., are you referring to the `elsarticle` document class?

Comment: Hi, Mico. It is exactly the document class I am referring to.

Comment: PLease, extend your code fragment to complete, compilable small document wit showed images.

Comment: Hi Zarko, I am confused. How do I do what you recommended?

Comment: I have submitted an edit suggestion to include a minimum working example. You'll want to edit it to more clearly outline your goal, but someone should be able to copy and paste your MWE and compile without any other steps. It helps those trying to help you.

Comment: Alright, I am waiting for the notification on that suggestion and will follow up ASAP. Thank you.

Comment: Please see the update of the answer after your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2** After the last edit.

The command `\p{<letter>}` insert the letters **a** or **b** close to the upper right corner of the figures.

`yshift` must be adjusted to place the letter in the desired height.

[image: e]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{elsarticle}
    
\usepackage{tikz}% needed <<<<<<<<<<
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark} % needed <<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\p}[1]{\tikzmarknode[label={[yshift=39mm,font=\bfseries\footnotesize]center:#1}]{#1}{}} % needed <<<<<<<<<<
        
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[t]\vspace*{4pt}
         \begin{center}
        \p{a}\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \hspace*{5mm}%
        \p{b}\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \end{center}        
        \caption{(a) first picture; (b) second picture.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

(The class `elsarticle` loads the package `graphicx`.)

Comment: Thank you, Simon, but I need to proceed based on the initial codes. Unfortunately, it seems to be a requirement.

Comment: Thank you, Simon, this one works perfectly. I am not able to select it as the answer that solved my problem, though.

Comment: Alright, I just figured it out. Thanks, @Simon.